# Having trouble normalizing distance between two 3D points

Tags: c++, graphics, distance, angle, particle-system

I have two 3D points and I am trying to get the distance between them. The points lie in the range of -1.0 to 1.0, with 0,0 being the center of the screen.

I know the way to figure out the distance is: distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);

But I am having trouble normalizing them to 0-1, I assume because there are negatives involved?

I am trying to calculate the distance a particle is from an attractor. I am trying to normalize the distance so that I know when the distance is 0, it has reached the attractor, and I can make it stop traveling.

Here is my code snippet. attractor is the attractor position. pos is the particle position. curtime is the time factor for incrementing the particle. attractorint is the intensity of the attractor force. Really, everything works as it should but I need to be able to know when the particle reaches the attractor and that's why I'm trying to normalize it's distance.

```
   float dx = attractorx - posx;
   float dy = attractory - posy;
   float dz = attractorz - posz;
   float distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
    
   float forceX = dx / distance;
   float forceY = dy / distance;
   float forceZ = dz / distance;
   float force = curtime * attractorint;
    
   posx += force * forceX;
   posy += force * forceY;
   posz += force * forceZ;
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thank you!

Comment: Start with a simpler problem: take a `float` variable, and try to detect when it is equal to zero. See the problem? The usual approach is to detect when its absolute value is less than some small positive epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that your gravity force is going to infinity as the objects approach each other. This is a mathematical abstraction.

A more realistic model would take the gravity reduction as one object intersects with the other as in the picture below taken from [OpenStax](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/13-2-gravitation-near-earths-surface).

So you could say something like this below. The single `if` line will make sure that the gravity force decays gradually to zero once the particles intercept, nullifying the issue with floating point infinity while being more authentic.

```cpp
   float dx = attractorx - posx;
   float dy = attractory - posy;
   float dz = attractorz - posz;
   float distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);

   if ( distance < radius ) distance = radius;

   float forceX = dx / distance;
   float forceY = dy / distance;
   float forceZ = dz / distance;

   float force = curtime * attractorint;
    
   posx += force * forceX;
   posy += force * forceY;
   posz += force * forceZ;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Henrique - thank you for your informative reply and suggestion. I tried it but the problem is that this still doesn't tell me when the particle reaches the attractor and thus, I'm still unable to stop it from continuing to travel beyond it. My distance isn't in the range of 0-1 and that's what I was hoping to achieve. 0 when it's emitted and 1 when it reaches the attractor.